# Safari bug .position()

Tags: jquery, web-applications, safari

I'm not sure if this is a bug with my code, or with Safari, but when using the code:

```
cx = $('.cart').position().top;
```

to trigger an alert on the page; it will trigger (work correctly) in all browsers but Safari. I am unsure why.

[Here is the page I am having the problem with!](http://partytime.v5.cloudsvr.com.au/-products/10m_x_3m_structure_maruee?product_qty%5B504e89250053dc960a0000c9%5D=1)

I'm using Safari version 3.2.2 by the way.

Comment: Works for me on Safari 5.1.7 (Win7).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the alert dialog is supposed to do but I got it to display fine in both Safari 5.1.7 and Chrome 22. I did however notice a discrepancy in the position returned. Below is the output of the dialog in each browser:

Output in Safari 5.1.7:

```
http://partytime.v5.cloudsvr.com.au
Cart is loaded: 1, X position: 1274px;
```

Output in Chrome 22:

```
Cart is loaded: 1, X position: 1260.5px;
```

Not sure if this is what you wanted/intended but it appears to be working correctly.

Comment: I've just tested this on a mac machine and it works fine, it might have something to do with my version, 3.2.2 if this helps.

Comment: That could very well be. Not sure how the older version of Safari would handle this. Very good point.